# Ruby on Rails - Search on Model Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, models

I want to be able to search and update the index.

this is my controller method:

```
def index
    if params[:search]
      @ofertas = Oferta.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:ofertas_page], :per_page => 5)
    else
      @ofertas = Oferta.all.paginate(page: params[:ofertas_page], :per_page => 5)
    end
  end
```

My search method in the model

```
def self.search(search)
    where("titulo like ?","%w{search}%")
  end
```

and this is the search form

```
<%= form_tag ofertas_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Procurar Entidades" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Procurar", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I've seen this setup in a number of search tutorials but no matter what I type nothing appears. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to interpolate the `search` variable into the string, but didn't quite get the right symbol. How about this:

```
"%#{search}%"
```

Note the `#` instead of the `w`.

Answer (score 2):

```
where("titulo like ?","%w{search}%")
```

should be:

```
where("titulo like ?", "%#{search}%")
```

`#{xxx}` is for string interpolation - it allows you to inject ruby (including variables) into a string.

`"%xxxx%"` is telling SQL that the search string can appear anywhere in the titulo column. '%' is a wildcard in SQL.

`%w{xxx yyy zzz}` is shorthand for `["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]` - an array in Ruby, which wouldn't mean much to the SQL as a string by itself.